# UIKit in Preview canvas doesn't comply with the option previewLayout

Tags: swiftui, uikit, swiftui-previews

I'm currently using UIKit for making views and now I want to preview it just like SwiftUI.
But my canvas preview looks like a device rather than the size of view itself.

What have I done wrong?

```
import UIKit

class MyYellowButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not support coder")
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    private func setupView() {
        backgroundColor = .yellow
        setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    }
}

#if canImport(SwiftUI) && DEBUG
import SwiftUI
struct UIViewPreview<View: UIView>: UIViewRepresentable {
    let view: View

    init(_ builder: @escaping () -> View) {
        view = builder()
    }

    // MARK: - UIViewRepresentable

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: UIView, context: Context) {
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
    }
}

struct MyYellowButtonPreview: PreviewProvider{
    static var previews: some View {
        UIViewPreview {
            let button = MyYellowButton(frame: .zero)
            button.setTitle("buttonTest", for: .normal)
            return button
        }.previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
#endif
```

I wanted my preview to look like this

Answer (score 0):

'.sizeThatFits' and '.fixed' arguments used by 'previewLayout' modifier display container view without device bezels and safe-area insets in selectable mode. In 'Live' mode, a view is always displayed as a device with bezels.